# Phaser game runs good on desktop but lags on mobile

Tags: javascript, html, android, html5

I am creating my first game using Phaser and it is running fine in desktop. But it is lagging on Android phones.

Can anyone tell me what could be the reasons?

The game is very small -- smaller than 2MB. The images used in the game are also very tiny .png files. Is there any way to find out any leaks in my code?

My main.js file:

```
var buttetSpwanSpeed;
var bulletSpeed;
var enemySpwanSpeed;
var enemySpeed;
var golis;
var enemies;
var enemyLoop;
var scoreText;
var powers;
var bulletSize;
setStart();
//game phaser
var game=new Phaser.Game(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight, Phaser.CANVAS,"gamearea");
var BootState={
    //loding accets
    preload: function(){
        this.load.image('LodingScreen', 'assets/desimulga.png');
        this.load.image('background', 'assets/blue.png');
    },
    create: function(){
        game.state.start("LoadingState");
    },

};

var LoadingState={
    //loding acc
    preload: function(){
        bg=this.game.add.tileSprite(0,0,600,300,'background');
        bg.height = game.height;
        bg.width = game.width;
        LodingScreen=this.game.add.sprite(this.game.world.centerX,this.game.world.centerY,'LodingScreen');
        LodingScreen.anchor.setTo(0.5);
        LodingScreen.scale.setTo(0.5,0.5);
        this.load.image('spaceship', 'assets/player.png');
        this.load.image('goli', 'assets/bullet.png');
        //load ememies
        this.load.image('enemy1', 'assets/enemies/enemy1.png');
        this.load.image('enemy2', 'assets/enemies/enemy2.png');
        this.load.image('enemy3', 'assets/enemies/enemy3.png');
        this.load.image('enemy4', 'assets/enemies/enemy4.png');
        this.load.image('enemy5', 'assets/enemies/enemy5.png');
        this.load.spritesheet('power1', 'assets/power/bulletUp.png',34,33,4);

        this.load.image('restart', 'assets/restart.png');
        this.load.spritesheet('blast', 'assets/explosion.png',400,400,8);
        game.load.audio('fire', 'assets/music/bullet.mp3');
        game.load.audio('killed', 'assets/music/killed.mp3');
        //game.load.audio('bg_music', 'assets/music/background.mp3');
        game.load.audio('death_music', 'assets/music/death.mp3');
        game.load.audio('start_music', 'assets/music/start.mp3');
    },
    create: function(){
        game.time.events.add(Phaser.Timer.SECOND * 2, function(){
            bg.kill();
            LodingScreen.kill();
            game.state.start("PreGameState");
    },this);
    },

};

var PreGameState={
    //loding accets
    create: function(){
        game.scale.refresh();
        bg=this.game.add.tileSprite(0,0,600,300,'background');
        bg.height = game.height;
        bg.width = game.width;
        Startb=this.game.add.text(this.game.world.centerX,this.game.world.centerY, 'TAP TO START' , { fontSize: '32px', fill: 'yellow' });
        Startb.anchor.setTo(0.5);
        Startb.scale.setTo(0.5,0.5);
        ship=this.game.add.sprite(this.game.world.centerX,this.game.world.height*0.4,'spaceship');
        ship.scale.setTo(0.4);
        ship.anchor.setTo(0.5);
        game.physics.arcade.enable(ship);
        bg.inputEnabled=true;

        start_music = game.add.audio('start_music');
        start_music.allowMultiple = true;
        start_music.addMarker('start_music', 0, 30);


        bg.events.onInputDown.add(function(){
            bg.inputEnabled=false;
            Startb.kill();
            start_music.play("start_music");
            // game.physics.arcade.moveToXY(ship, this.game.world.centerX, this.game.world.height*0.8, 300, 3000);
            // game.add.tween(ship).to( { y: game.world.height*0.8 }, 3000, Phaser.Easing.Sinusoidal.InOut, true);
            var tween = game.add.tween(ship).to({
            x: [this.game.world.centerX, this.game.world.width*0, this.game.world.width, this.game.world.centerX],
            y: [this.game.world.height*0.4, this.game.world.height*0.5, this.game.world.height*0.6, this.game.world.height*0.8],
            }, 2000,Phaser.Easing.Quadratic.Out, true).interpolation(function(v, k){
                return Phaser.Math.bezierInterpolation(v, k);
            });

            game.time.events.add(Phaser.Timer.SECOND * 2, function() { 
                bg.kill();
                ship.kill();
                game.state.start("GameState");
            } ,this);

        }, this);
    },

};





var GameState={
    //loding accets
    preload: function(){


    },
    create: function(){
        //background
        this.background=this.game.add.tileSprite(0,0,600,300,'background');
        this.background.height = game.height;
        this.background.width = game.width;
        this.background.inputEnabled=true;
        this.background.input.enableDrag(true);
        this.background.input.startDrag = function(pointer) {
            pointer.shipStart = new Phaser.Point(GameState.ship.x, GameState.ship.y);
            Phaser.InputHandler.prototype.startDrag.call(this, pointer);
        };
        this.background.input.updateDrag = function(pointer) {
            GameState.ship.x = pointer.shipStart.x - pointer.positionDown.x + pointer.x;
            GameState.ship.y = pointer.shipStart.y - pointer.positionDown.y + pointer.y;
            GameState.background.x=0;
            GameState.background.y=0;
        };
        //ship
        this.ship=this.game.add.sprite(this.game.world.centerX,this.game.world.height*0.8,'spaceship');
        this.ship.scale.setTo(0.4);
        this.ship.anchor.setTo(0.5);
        game.physics.arcade.enable(this.ship);
        // this.ship.inputEnabled=true;
        // this.ship.input.enableDrag(true);
        //score
        this.scoreText = this.game.add.text(16, 16, 'Kills: 0', { fontSize: '32px', fill: '#fff' });
        //background Music
        // music = game.add.audio('bg_music');
        //music.play('', 0, 1, true);
        //bullet sound
        bullet_sound = game.add.audio('fire');
        bullet_sound.allowMultiple = true;
        bullet_sound.volume=0.5;
        bullet_sound.addMarker('fire', 0, 0.5);
        //Killed sound
        killed_sound = game.add.audio('killed');
        killed_sound.allowMultiple = true;
        killed_sound.addMarker('killed', 0, 0.5);
        //death music
        death_music = game.add.audio('death_music');
        death_music.allowMultiple = true;
        death_music.addMarker('death_music', 0, 10);
        //groups of bullets and enemies
        golis=game.add.group();
        enemies=game.add.group();
        powers=game.add.group();
        //fire bullet loop
        fireLoop=game.time.events.loop(Phaser.Timer.SECOND*1/buttetSpwanSpeed, fireBullet, this);
        //this.game.input.onTap.add(fireBullet, this);
        //create ememy loop
        enemyLoop=game.time.events.loop(Phaser.Timer.SECOND*1/enemySpwanSpeed, createEnemy, this);
        //change ememy speed and enemy spwan speed loop
        enemySpeedLoop=game.time.events.loop(Phaser.Timer.SECOND*1.5, changeEnemySpeed, this);
        //give powerup
        powerUp=game.time.events.loop(Phaser.Timer.SECOND*20, powerFun, this);      
    },
    update: function(){
        //scrolling background
        this.background.tilePosition.y+=2;

        //keybord control
        if (game.input.keyboard.isDown(Phaser.Keyboard.UP))
        {
            this.ship.y-=2;
        }
        if (game.input.keyboard.isDown(Phaser.Keyboard.DOWN))
        {
            this.ship.y+=2;
        }
        if (game.input.keyboard.isDown(Phaser.Keyboard.RIGHT))
        {
            this.ship.x+=2;
        }
        if (game.input.keyboard.isDown(Phaser.Keyboard.LEFT))
        {
            this.ship.x-=2;
        }

        //dont go out
        if(this.ship.y<0+this.ship.height/2)
        {
            this.ship.y=0+this.ship.height/2;
        }
        if(this.ship.y>this.game.world.height-this.ship.height/2)
        {
            this.ship.y=this.game.world.height-this.ship.height/2;
        }

        if(this.ship.x<0+this.ship.width/2)
        {
            this.ship.x=0+this.ship.width/2;
        }
        if(this.ship.x>this.game.world.width-this.ship.width/2)
        {
            this.ship.x=this.game.world.width-this.ship.width/2;
        }
        //check for collisions 
        game.physics.arcade.overlap(golis,enemies,b_e_collide,null,this);
        game.physics.arcade.overlap(this.ship,enemies,s_e_collide,null,this);
        game.physics.arcade.overlap(this.ship,powers,s_power1_collide,null,this);




    },
};


//setting start game conditions
function setStart(){
    buttetSpwanSpeed=2;
    bulletSpeed=2000;
    enemySpwanSpeed=1;
    enemySpeed=300;
    score=0;
    bulletSize=1.2
}

//fire bullet function
function fireBullet(){
    goli=this.game.add.sprite(this.ship.x,this.ship.y-this.ship.height/2,'goli');
    goli.anchor.setTo(0.5);
    goli.scale.setTo(bulletSize,1);
    goli.checkWorldBounds = true;
    goli.outOfBoundsKill = true;
    //adding to group
    golis.add(goli);
    game.world.moveDown(goli);
    game.physics.arcade.enable(goli);
    goli.body.collisonWorldBounds=true;
    goli.body.velocity.y=-bulletSpeed;
    bullet_sound.play("fire");
}
//create enemy function
function createEnemy(){
    enemyNo=game.rnd.integerInRange(1, 5);
    x1=game.rnd.integerInRange(0,this.game.world.width);
    x2=game.rnd.integerInRange(0,this.game.world.width);
    enemy=this.game.add.sprite(x1,10,'enemy'+enemyNo);
    enemy.anchor.setTo(0.5);
    enemy.scale.setTo(0.4);
    enemy.checkWorldBounds = true;
    enemies.add(enemy);
    enemy.outOfBoundsKill = true;
    game.physics.arcade.enable(enemy);
    enemy.body.collisonWorldBounds=true;
    enemy.angle=90;
    enemy.no=enemyNo;

    //moving enemy
    angleRedian=game.physics.arcade.moveToXY(enemy, x2, this.game.world.height+enemy.height, enemySpeed,0);
    angleDegree=angleRedian*57.2958;
    enemy.angle=90+angleDegree;

}

//runs when bullet collide to enemy
function b_e_collide(goli,enemy){
    //blast
    blast=this.game.add.sprite(enemy.x,enemy.y,'blast');
    blast.anchor.setTo(0.5);
    blast.scale.setTo(0.5);
    var explosion=blast.animations.add('explosion');
    blast.animations.play('explosion',30,false,true);

    //killing
    goli.kill();
    enemy.kill();

    //update scores
    if(enemy.no<4)
    {
        score+=1;
        killed_sound.play('killed');
    }
    this.scoreText.text = 'Kills: ' + score;
}
//runs when ship collide to enemy
function s_e_collide(ship,enemy){

    blast=this.game.add.sprite(enemy.x,enemy.y,'blast');
    blast.anchor.setTo(0.5);
    blast.scale.setTo(0.5);
    var explosion=blast.animations.add('explosion');
    blast.animations.play('explosion',10,false,true);
    ship.kill();
    enemy.kill();
    //music.stop();
    this.scoreText.kill();
    death_music.play("death_music");
    game.time.events.remove(fireLoop);
    game.time.events.add(Phaser.Timer.SECOND * 2, function() {    
        fianlScore = this.game.add.text(this.game.world.centerX,this.game.world.centerY, 'KILL: '+score, { fontSize: '32px', fill: 'yellow' });
        fianlScore.anchor.setTo(0.5);
        gameOverText = this.game.add.text(this.game.world.centerX,this.game.world.centerY - fianlScore.height, 'GAME OVER', { fontSize: '32px', fill: 'red' });
        gameOverText.anchor.setTo(0.5);
        //restart button
        restart=this.game.add.sprite(this.game.world.centerX,this.game.world.centerY + fianlScore.height+10,'restart');
        restart.anchor.setTo(0.5);
        restart.scale.setTo(0.05,0.05);
        restart.inputEnabled = true;
        restart.events.onInputDown.add(restartGame, this);
        game.time.events.stop();
    }, this);

}
//runs when ship collide power1
function s_power1_collide(ship,power){
    power.kill();
    game.time.events.remove(fireLoop);
    fireLoop=game.time.events.loop(Phaser.Timer.SECOND*1/10, fireBullet, this);
    game.time.events.add(Phaser.Timer.SECOND * 10, function(){
        game.time.events.remove(fireLoop);
        fireLoop=game.time.events.loop(Phaser.Timer.SECOND*1/buttetSpwanSpeed, fireBullet, this);
    },this);



}


function changeEnemySpeed()
{   
    if(enemySpeed<=900)
    {
        enemySpeed+=5;
    }
    if(enemySpwanSpeed<=3)
    {
        enemySpwanSpeed+=0.025;
    }
    enemyLoop.delay=Phaser.Timer.SECOND*1/enemySpwanSpeed;
}

//send power up
function powerFun()
{
    x1=game.rnd.integerInRange(0,this.game.world.width);
    x2=game.rnd.integerInRange(0,this.game.world.width);
    power=this.game.add.sprite(x1,10,'power1');
    power.anchor.setTo(0.5);
    var shine=power.animations.add('shine');
    power.animations.play('shine',5,true,true);
    power.checkWorldBounds = true;
    power.outOfBoundsKill = true;
    powers.add(power);
    game.physics.arcade.enable(power);
    power.body.collisonWorldBounds=true;
    game.physics.arcade.moveToXY(power, x2, this.game.world.height+power.height, 400,0);
    powerDelay=game.rnd.integerInRange(20,35);
    powerUp.delay=Phaser.Timer.SECOND*powerDelay;
}



function restartGame(){
    setStart();
    game.time.events.start();
    game.state.start("PreGameState");   
}



game.state.add("GameState",GameState);
game.state.add("BootState",BootState);
game.state.add("LoadingState",LoadingState);
game.state.add("PreGameState",PreGameState);
game.state.start("BootState");
```

Since the game is so small in size, I think it should run smoothly on mobile devices. It runs good on some high-end mobile devices but gets slow as time progresses. This is my first game so I am not very good with game designing concepts.

Comment: The reason that it lags on mobile is because computer desktop is just faster than mobile. Mobile is slower than computer desktop in speed processing.

Comment: @ErezZrihen there are quite a lot of games that are not lagging so your comment is so not helpful :-]

Comment: yes, and game is very small

Comment: smaller than 2mb and i want it to run on mobile too,
can anyone find any leaks in my code ?

Comment: You need to locate the source/s of slow down. To do that you disable parts of the game, then run i. Then ask, has the performance increase. One at a time do things like, disable all collisions, don't add enemy, disable the sounds, change the canvas size to half, reduce the tile count, etc This will give you a feel of where the slowdowns are, then you can address problem. The mobile version will always be slower than the desktop. You just have to find what can be removed/changed and still keep the gameplay enjoyable.

Comment: Oh and I just saw in your code that you have everything at scale 0.5. This is bad. Scale should be 1 or greater than one. Change everything so that you set the scale to 1, this will mean going into photoshop and doing the scaling in there. For the game with a scale of 0.5 you have 4times more pixel that need to be moved, most of which will not be clearly seen. Then try my first comment.

Comment: ohk your comment is very useful 
i will surly try these and comment back

Comment: removing tileSprite make huge diff.
there are much less lags now

Answer (score 1):

Please use "spawn" where appropriate, e.g. bulletSpawnSpeed instead of buttetSpwanSpeed.

Sorry, I didn't notice any obvious leaks.

Typo:     //loding accets -> // loading assets

Yes, I agree with Blindman67 - disable much of the game, verify "fast" or "no leak", then keep adding back pieces until things go south.